# customize the audio tag position

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML code:

```
<body id="mybg">

<div id="countdown-11"></div>
<br>
<audio id="myaudio" src="music/forestsounds.ogg" controls="controls" loop="loop"></audio>
</body>
```

where the `<div>` is a coundown timer, I want to put the audio component below the countdown timer... in this case they are superimposed.

I tried with this CSS code:

```
#myaudio{
bottom: 10px;
}
```

But no result. What's wrong?

Comment: Add #countdown-11 { clear:both; } may fix your issue

Comment: i try it, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please provide a JSFIDDLE to see what is happening? or provide an image how it looks right now?

Comment: here is a picture: http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/653709screen1.png

Comment: Do you need a result like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/T3WZe/3/) ?

Comment: I put the audio in a div/span tag, but it doesn't work.. I want that the audio tag will be under the countdown timer.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add to the audio tag in the css the following code:

```
position: absolute;
```

then use top, left, etc. to move it.

Answer (score 0):

Use Position Absolute to change the position of the div dynamically

```
#myaudio
{
   position:absolute;
   top:10%;
   left:10%;
}
```

The percentage values can be changed depending on where you want the "myaudio" div to go

Hope This Helps :)

Answer (score 0):

As we have discussed, [This Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T3WZe/8/) is fulfill your requirement.

**CSS Code:**

```
#countdown-11{
  clear:both;
  background: #444 !important;
  color:#FFF;
  margin:4px;
  padding:4px;
}
#myaudio{
   clear:both;
}
```